# Produce a list of entries that have no relationship parents

Tags: playa, relationships, parent, children

I've got an EE 2.6 site that has pages (no duh) as entries, and some of those pages have children (i.e. via a relationship field).

Now, what I'd like to do is generate a list of the pages that do not have parents. But I don't see any way to do this.  I would prefer native related entries, but would be fine with using Playa... but it doesn't seem to offer this functionality either. Am I stuck with using a query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use query module also like:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT exp_channel_titles.entry_id, exp_channel_titles.title FROM exp_channel_titles LEFT JOIN exp_relationships ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id=exp_relationships.rel_child_id WHERE exp_relationships.rel_child_id IS NULL AND exp_channel_titles.channel_id=1 AND exp_channel_titles.status='open'"}

{entry_id} :: {title}

{/exp:query}
```

Check the WHERE condition having "channel_id" and "status", you can change according to your preference.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, this seems to do the trick. It's limited because it only shows entries that have NO children at all, not just in one the particular field/relationship that I want to check -- and I want to filter by category, too, so that's tricky! -- but this got me started and was a good answer to the question.  Thank you.

Comment: @TravisSmith: glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Travis -

Throw this into a blank template, replace the field name of course:

```
    <h2>pt_playa="IS_EMPTY"</h2>

{exp:channel:entries search:pt_playa="IS_EMPTY"}

{title}<br />

{/exp:channel:entries}

<hr />

<h2>pt_playa="not IS_EMPTY"</h2>

{exp:channel:entries search:pt_playa="not IS_EMPTY"}

{title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You'll see that search can help you here, at least if I am understanding correctly :) But I think I may be reversed from what you want.

My testing was done with a Playa relationship field....

-Lisa P&T

Comment: I believe this shows entries with and without children, not with and without parents.

Comment: Yea, I was totally reversed.  Sorry Travis :( What about Bhashkar's answer?